# I am using formsauthentication in my application but it is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is my code for forms authentication in asp.net but some time it is not working means some time user is not logged in

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(authentificationString, rememberLogin);

```
        string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
        HttpCookie authCookie = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[cookieName].Domain = Utilities.ResponseManager.CookieDomain;
        }
```

It is working fine in my local machine but when I deploy on my server then it is not working.

is it any iss setting or something else..
what I need to do for this.

below is web.config code

and local machine having IIS 6.0 and Server having IIS 7.0

Please help me out on this problem

Comment: please also post relevant sections of web.config and also try to describe the current configuration of IIS (and which version of IIS?)

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed web.config configuration. Saying that yhou want to use Forms Authentication instead of Window?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have this section in your application web.config

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms" />
</system.web>
```

And go in server IIS manager and ensure Forms authentication is enabled and any other authentication mode is disabled for the application.
I hope this solves your problem.